# How to do multilevel indexing on array of structs in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, data-structures, indexing

Let's say I create an array of structs in matlab using:

```
mystruct = repmat(struct('field1',1, 'field2', ones(10,1)), 10, 1 );
```

For my purposes (simple example aside), I would find it very useful to get a vector output from using:

```
myvector = mystruct(:).field2(1)
```

However this gives me the error:

```
'Scalar index required for this type of multi-level indexing.'
```

EDIT: What I expect to get is the first element of the ones vector, from each struct in the array, hence a 10x1 vector of '1'.

I could easily manually using a for loop go through each value in my struct and assign to myvector but that seems incredibly cumbersome and also slow. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to collect all of the `field2` vectors into `myvector`:

```
myvector = [mystruct(:).field2];
```

Returns:

```
myvector =

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

EDIT: Per your comment, you can use the above and throw out the data you don't want (`myvector(2:end,:) = [];` in this case). This is a pretty memory intensive way to do it though. There may be a way to pull what you want using [`structfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/structfun.html) or similar but I'd need to think about how to do it.

EDIT2: Try `arrayfun(@(x) x.field2(1), mystruct)` and see if this returns what you're looking for.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer, I should have specified what I want: I basically want all the first elements from field2 in each struct in the array of structs. Ill modify my question but I think you have pretty much got it there.

Comment: Updated based on your comment, I will look at it again later to try and come up with a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

In two step you can:

1. get your struct filed2 as a matrix:

   foo = [mystruct.field2];
2. get the first row (that contains the first indices of the field2)

   myvector = foo(1, :);

Comment: Thanks, that is it, so I take it there is no single command, I will always need to break it into two steps?